# Combobox : Why comboBox_SelectionChanged is null when I set the default value with SelectedValue?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I code this code for my ComboBox :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableStrings}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentStrings}" Name="availableStrings" SelectionChanged="availableStrings_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And then in the code-behind I have :

```
private void availableStrings_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string currentText = availableStrings.SelectedValue as string;
}
```

I tried to debug and I got the following behaviour in this order :

- 1st, `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentStrings}"` calls the `get {...}` of my property and JUST after that :
- `availableStrings_SelectionChanged` is called and `availableStrings.SelectedValue` is null ?!?

My SelectedValue Binding just called the `get` and get the value oO
It seems like availableStrings_SelectionChanged is called before the value had been assigned the my combobox.. and it sounds like a bug to me no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Set on CurrentStrings to get current values and CurrentStrings should NOT be an array (it should be singular).  Bind the SelectedValue TwoWay and don't use SelectionChanged.

Comment: this really is a strange behaviour... !

Comment: In fact, this can be logical if u want to do some tests before effectively set the new value

Comment: What is strange?   I am pretty sure the SelectedValue did not have a Set so the UI had no place to store the value so it was null.  XAML binding does not throw an error.